# Is there an easy way to generate an ERD Diagram from a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, erd

I am trying to generate an ERD diagram using a csv file that has 2 columns, TableName and ColumnName. Is there a package out there that can generate such a thing? (Visual representation of the interrelationships between the tables & columns, generalizable to any tuple-pairs, really)

ex:
**TableName,ColumnName**
TABLE1,COLUMN1
TABLE1,COLUMN2
TABLE2,COLUMN1
...
TABLEN,COLUMNM
TABLEN,COLUMNN

and so on.

Thanks!